# How to pass variable to child function from HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to pass a value from HTML page to child function from parent function.

HTML Page:

```
<div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">

  <div class="message_input_wrapper">
    <input class="message_input" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
  </div>

  <div class="send_message">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">Send/div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent Function Call:

```
$('.send_message').click(function (e) {
  return [sendMessage(getMessageText()),sendMessage1(getMessageText1())];
});

$('.message_input').keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    return [sendMessage(getMessageText()),sendMessage1(getMessageText1())];
  }
});
```

here `getMessageText1` is child function.

Child Function:

```
getMessageText1 = function () {
  var result="";
  var id = Parent_FUNC_INPUT;
  $.ajax({
    url:"func.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({id:id}),
    async: false,  
    success:function(data) {
      result = data; 
    }
  });
```

I want to populate [[id]] variable in child function from parent function.

Comment: Have you tried passing that value as a function parameter/argument?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll do my best to clean up the HTML:

```
<div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="message_input_wrapper">
        <input class="message_input" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
    </div>
    <div class="send_message">
        <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Send</div>
</div>
```

Using proper indentation will make things far easier to read. And while we're on the subject, you may want to use dashes `-` instead of underscores `_` in your class names, as that's the common convention.

On to your question, it seems like what you want to do is simply **pass an argument to `getMessageText1`** from within (as you refer to it) a "parent" function bound to an event listener.

So you'd define this "child" function with a single parameter:

```
function getMessageText1(Parent_FUNC_INPUT) {
    ...
    var id = Parent_FUNC_INPUT;
    ...
}
```

And then you can just call it with `getMessageText1(value)` where value is whatever you want to pass in.

One more note: for readability's sake I recommend you do not name your functions the way you have. Having two functions `getMessageText` and `getMessageText1` will just be a source of confusion later on. Instead, think of something more descriptive, ala `getMessageTextFromID`.

Hopefully I answered the question you meant to ask. Let me know.